# JQUERY: How to reduce code if i have multiple fields that i control validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, performance

For example i have 3 function that i control the keydown of each field; at the end i control the same so i want to put the 3 fields with code 1 time only.

```
ens_q_frio.keydown(function (event) {

    if (event.shiftKey == true) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 190) {

    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if ($(this).val().indexOf('.') !== -1 && event.keyCode == 190)
        event.preventDefault();
});

ens_q_cal.keydown(function (event) {

    if (event.shiftKey == true) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 190) {

    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if ($(this).val().indexOf('.') !== -1 && event.keyCode == 190)
        event.preventDefault();
});

ens_t_frio.keydown(function (event) {

    if (event.shiftKey == true) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 190) {

    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if ($(this).val().indexOf('.') !== -1 && event.keyCode == 190)
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a function:

```
function validate(event) {
  if (event.shiftKey == true) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 190) {

        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        if($(this).val().indexOf('.') !== -1 && event.keyCode == 190)
            event.preventDefault();
}
```

And pass it to the event:

```
ens_t_frio.keydown(validate);
```

Do the same thing for other inputs.

Comment: this example can be simplified to `ens_t_frio.keydown(validate);`

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction, it can be used without the anonymous function. Snippet edited.

Answer (score -1):

Have the argument of keydown as a separate function and then just pass it instead. You can also use forEach if your fields are in an array

Answer (score -1):

you can put it in a function and have it on each event handler.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#ens_q_frio").keydown(function(event){
     KeyDownEvent("ens_q_frio", event);
  });
  
  $("#ens_q_cal").keydown(function(event){    
    KeyDownEvent("ens_q_cal", event);
  });
  
   $("#ens_t_frio").keydown(function(event){
    KeyDownEvent("ens_t_frio", event);
   });
})

function KeyDownEvent(txtBox, event){
  if (event.shiftKey == true) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 190) {

  } 
  else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  if($("#" + txtBox).val().indexOf('.') !== -1 && event.keyCode == 190)
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ens_q_frio"/>
<input type="text" id="ens_q_cal"/>
<input type="text" id="ens_t_frio"/>
```